# Is it possible to run both drupal 6 and drupal 7 on local MAMP server?

Tags: drupal-6, localhost, drupal-7, mamp

I have a drupal 6 multisite setup on my local MAMP server. I don't want to upgrade these sites to drupal 7 as some of the modules have not been converted to drupal 7 yet. I would also like to start using drupal 7 on the MAMP server for new sites. However, I can't find a way to configure it so that both versions of drupal can run a multisite setup side by side (without interfering with each other).

Anyone done this with success? Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Pure drupal multisite need to run the same drupal version.

You can still have your D6 in, for exemple, www/drupal6/ and your D7 in www/drupal7/, that will work.

Comment: thanks @Haza - I'm specifically looking to run both on local computer for development purposes. I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Does it mean I would need a different server for each but could be on the same machine maybe - different ports?

Comment: You can run both on the same machine, Haza meant that you could have 2 Drupal installations in separate sub-folders of the server "document root". For example, in your browser you could reach the sites by: `http://localhost/drupal6` and `http://localhost/drupal7`

Comment: @Laxman13 - I have tried to do this but whenever I navigate to my drupal7 folder it displays the main drupal6 site. I have added the drupal7 folder as another domain in my etc/hosts file but they keep getting mixed up anyway. Is there a good tutorial that you know of to configure this properly. There must be one step I am missing here.

Comment: ok, I think I understand that it has to be a single site installation of each version in order to work and NOT multisite. Is that the just of it? More's the pity as would dearly love to start working with d7 but need to keep the d6 multisite going for now. Correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: @kristin.e that sounds right, you have to have each Drupal version running as a single site, they cannot work as multisite with each other

Answer (score 0):

Here is a caution, but I have not yet figured out the root of the issue (my searching for it led me to this question!). I had OpenAtrium (Drupal6) and Drupal 7 running successfully side-by-side as described above on a dev machine (separate directories, separate databases, separate etc/host domains, etc). In trying to work through an OpenAtrium image-upload issue (Clean URLs is a must), somehow, one of the admin buttons I clicked in OpenAtrium (I believe it was the OA option to repair permissions) completely trashed my Drupal 7 site. Since this was all dev/experimental, no data was lost, but be forewarned that bad things might happen.